# What is the use of #keyPath rather than directly passing key as a String?

Tags: swift, directive, kvc

What is the useful difference between these two formats:

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"dateCreated", ascending: false)]
```

and

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Note.dateCreated), ascending: false)]
```

In the second format #keyPath is confusing to me. What exactly it is and where I can read more about this?

Comment: The huge advantage of the `#keyPath` syntax is that the compiler validates the key path at **compile time** and throws an error if it's invalid.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for this clarification. But what we call #keyPath? Where I can read more like this?

Comment: It's described in the proposal [SE 0062](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0062-objc-keypaths.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between

```
key:"dateCreated"
```

and

```
key: #keyPath(Note.dateCreated)
```

both will do the sort with  `Note`  object's `dateCreated` property
the latter has an advantage of avoiding hard coding problems e.x writing `datCreated` instead of `dateCreated` will throw a compile time error , so it'll safely avoid run-time crashes that definitely will happen with the former under same circumstances

https://www.klundberg.com/blog/swift-4-keypaths-and-you/

http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/sort-descriptors-in-swift/

Comment: `#keyPath(Note.dateCreated)` will be autocompleted, `key:"dateCreated"` won't, I think that's the only difference. Functionally they are the same.

Comment: yes, even if being wrote wrongly compiler will throw an error , this is what i meant by hardcoded

Comment: Thanks! But what we call #keyPath? Where I can read more like this?